# Programatically Break Apart a PDF created by a scanner into separate PDF documents

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, pdf, adobe

I have PDF documents from a scanner. This PDF contain forms filled out and signed by staff for a days work.  I want to place a bar code or standard area for OCR text on every form type so the batch scan can be programatically broken apart into separate PDF document based on form type.

I would like to do this in Microsoft .net 2.0

I can purchase the require Adobe or other namespaces/dll need to accomplish the task if there are no open source namespaces/dll's available.

Answer (score 2):

Not a free or open source option, but you might also look at [ABCPdf by webSuperGoo](http://www.webgoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm) as another alternative to Adobe.

Answer (score 1):

You can research the iTextSharp library, which can split pdf files.
But it isn't very good for reading the actual pdfs.  So I have no idea how it would know where to split them.

There are companies that already do this for you.
You can research the kwiktag company.

Answer (score 1):

iTextSharp will help you split, reassemble, and apply barcodes to pdf's in .NET languages. I dont think it can OCR a document, but I havent looked (I used Abby fine Reader engine).

Answer (score 1):

From the title of your question I'm assuming that you just need to break apart PDF files and that they are already OCR'd.  There are a few open source .NET PDF libraries out there.  I have successfully used [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/) in a project of my own.

Here is a quick snippet that shows how to cull out each page from a PDF document using PDFSharp:

```
string filePath = @"c:\file.pdf";

using (PdfDocument ipdf = PdfReader.Open(filePath, PdfDocumentOpenMode.ReadOnly))
{
    int i = 1;
    foreach (PdfPage page in ipdf.Pages)
    {
        using (PdfDocument opdf = new PdfDocument())
        {
            opdf.Version = ipdf.Version;
            opdf.AddPage(page);

            opdf.Save("page " + i++ + ".pdf");
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming also that you need to access the text in the document for grouping you can use the PdfPage.Contents property.

Answer (score 0):

check out the [Tesseract .NET wrapper (v 2.04.0)](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/) around the c++ ocr engine by the same name developed by hp in the late 90's, it won awards for its ingenuity

Answer (score 0):

You can use several, try these free tools:

- [PDF Toolkit](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)
- [Multivalent](http://multivalent.sourceforge.net/Tools/index.html)